# Let $(\Bbb R,*)$ be such that $x*y = |x|y$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$. Show that $(\Bbb R,*)$ is not a group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $(\Bbb R,*)$ be the mathematical system defined as: $x*y = |x|y$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$. Show that $(\Bbb R,*)$ is not a group.

**Attempt:**
I have shown the assosiative property.
Now, I have to find an identity element in $(\Bbb R,*)$.

Let $m \in \Bbb R$ be the identity element in $(\Bbb R,*)$. Let $y \in \Bbb R$. Then,
\begin{align*}
m*y &= y \\
|m|y &= y \\
m=1 &\vee m=-1
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
y*m &= y \\
|y|m &= y \ldots (k)
\end{align*}
If $y \ge 0$, then $(k)$ becomes
$ym=y$ i.e. $m=1$.

If $y < 0$, then $(k)$ becomes
$-ym=y$ i.e. $m=-1$.

Thus, in two cases, we see that $m$ have two values. But, the identity element of a group must be unique. Hence, $(\Bbb R,*)$ has no an identity element i.e. is not a group. In particularly, $(\Bbb R,*)$ is a semigroup.

Is the above true?

Comment: Firstly, replace $y\geq 0$ with $y>0$. If $y=0$ then $ym=y$ no matter what $m$ is. Secondly, you have just shown that this isn't a group, but you're mixing up exactly how. You haven't shown that there are multiple identities, that's impossible by the very nature of an identity. You've shown that there is no identity, since the identity would need to satisfy $|y|m=y$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$, but this is impossible. Also, note that only what you've written after the line "and" is necessary for the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that each group $G$ has exactly one idempotent, for if $x\in G$ such that $x^2=x$, then $x=x^{-1}x^2=x^{-1}x=e$.

But in $(\Bbb R,\ast)$, we have $(-1)\ast(-1)=|-1|(-1)=-1$ and $1\ast 1=|1|(1)=1$.

Hence $(\Bbb R,\ast)$ is not a group.

Comment: In "But, in ...$, is it refers to the identity element is not unique and hence is not group?

Comment: Precisely, @user795084.

Comment: Anyway, what about my approach above Sir? Any mistakes or something?

Comment: See Thomas Anton's comment, @user795084.

Comment: Ooh, okay. Noted.

Comment: Wait: it means that there's more than one *idempotent*; we needn't show that each idempotent is an identity, since it needn't be: for example, $0\ast 0=|0|(0)=0$, so $0$ is an idempotent but it is clearly not an identity, @user795084.